# Bootstrap v4.0.0-alpha.6 card-group content not align to top

Tags: flexbox, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

Using CDNs from Bootstrap  v4.0.0-alpha.6 website, I cannot solve the flexbox to alight the card content to the top:[image: card-group content not aligned to top]

When I add `align-items-start` to the `card-group`, like this:

```
<div class="card-group align-items-start">
```

the card alignment is improved, then the border boxes are out of line and missing segments where they were previously joined:[image: <code>card-group borders mis-aligned</code>]

There are no style-sheet changes to bootstrap-4a6 published version.  Here is my html:

```
<section id="what-we-do" style="padding: 20px 0px;">
  <div class="section-content">
    <div class="container">
      <h2>What we do</h2>
      <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
      tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
      quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
      consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
      cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
      proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="card-group align-items-start">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-block">
                <h4 class="card-title">Strategy &amp; Planning</h4>
                <h6 class="card-subtitle">Support card subtitle</h6>
              </div>
              <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="img/chalkboard.jpg" alt="a chalkboard">
              <div class="card-block">
                <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam repellendus est rerum sed, aliquid inventore, voluptate, eveniet, soluta nostrum distinctio cupiditate adipisci sint! Natus consequuntur non distinctio perferendis, quibusdam, quasi!</p>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success-outline" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">learn more</button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-block">
                <h4 class="card-title">Creative &amp; Design</h4>
                <h6 class="card-subtitle">Support card subtitle</h6>
              </div>
              <img class="card-img-bottom img-fluid" src="img/working.jpg" alt="working on a laptop">
                <div class="card-block">
                  <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed alias maxime fugiat error doloribus eum, aliquam deserunt ut sequi asperiores iure natus blanditiis commodi eveniet ipsam veniam eius eos. Sit!  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam repellendus est rerum sed, aliquid inventore, voluptate, eveniet, soluta nostrum distinctio cupiditate adipisci sint! Natus consequuntur non distinctio perferendis, quibusdam, quasi!</p>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success-outline" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">learn more</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-block">
                <h4 class="card-title">Programming &amp; Technical</h4>
                <h6 class="card-subtitle">Support card subtitle</h6>
              </div>
              <img class="card-img-bottom img-fluid" src="img/programming.jpg" alt="fingers typing on a keyboard">
                <div class="card-block">
                  <p class="card-text">Numquam repellendus est rerum sed, aliquid inventore, voluptate, eveniet, soluta nostrum distinctio cupiditate adipisci sint! Natus consequuntur non distinctio perferendis, quibusdam, quasi!</p>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success-outline" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">learn more</button>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The separated `.card-block`s are the problem. Instead, centralise all the content into one `.card-block` will fix your problem.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<section id="what-we-do" style="padding: 20px 0px;">
    <div class="section-content">
        <div class="container">
            <h2>What we do</h2>
            <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div class="card-group">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-block">
                                <h4 class="card-title">Strategy &amp; Planning</h4>
                                <h6 class="card-subtitle">Support card subtitle</h6>
                                <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="img/chalkboard.jpg" alt="a chalkboard">
                                <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam
                                    repellendus est rerum sed, aliquid inventore, voluptate, eveniet, soluta nostrum
                                    distinctio cupiditate adipisci sint! Natus consequuntur non distinctio perferendis,
                                    quibusdam, quasi!</p>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success-outline" data-toggle="modal"
                                        data-target="#myModal">learn more
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-block">
                                <h4 class="card-title">Creative &amp; Design</h4>
                                <h6 class="card-subtitle">Support card subtitle</h6>
                                <img class="card-img-bottom img-fluid" src="img/working.jpg" alt="working on a laptop">
                                <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed alias
                                    maxime fugiat error doloribus eum, aliquam deserunt ut sequi asperiores iure natus
                                    blanditiis commodi eveniet ipsam veniam eius eos. Sit! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
                                    consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam repellendus est rerum sed, aliquid inventore,
                                    voluptate, eveniet, soluta nostrum distinctio cupiditate adipisci sint! Natus
                                    consequuntur non distinctio perferendis, quibusdam, quasi!</p>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success-outline" data-toggle="modal"
                                        data-target="#myModal">learn more
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-block">
                                <h4 class="card-title">Programming &amp; Technical</h4>
                                <h6 class="card-subtitle">Support card subtitle</h6>
                                <img class="card-img-bottom img-fluid" src="img/programming.jpg"
                                     alt="fingers typing on a keyboard">
                                <p class="card-text">Numquam repellendus est rerum sed, aliquid inventore, voluptate,
                                    eveniet, soluta nostrum distinctio cupiditate adipisci sint! Natus consequuntur non
                                    distinctio perferendis, quibusdam, quasi!</p>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success-outline" data-toggle="modal"
                                        data-target="#myModal">learn more
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: This creates padding around the images too.

Comment: `.card-block` has padding by default. This isn't a problem with the code.

Comment: I know it has padding, but @STWilson card images do not have padding around them.

Answer (score 0):

Since the `card-block` is `flex-grow: 1`, the 2 `card-block`'s in each card are growing equally to fill the space above and below the image. Since you only want the bottom `card-block` to grow, use a simple padded div (`<div class="p-3">`) to hold the `card-title` and `card-subtitle` instead of `card-block`.

```
<div class="card">
       <div class="p-3">
            <h4 class="card-title">Strategy &amp; Planning</h4>
            <h6 class="card-subtitle">Support card subtitle</h6>
       </div>
       <img class="img-fluid" src="//placehold.it/600" alt="a chalkboard">
       <div class="card-block">
          <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipsicing elit. Numquam repellendus est rerum sed, aliquid inventore, voluptate, eveniet, soluta nostrum distinctio cupiditate adipisci sint! Natus consequuntur non distinctio perferendis, quibusdam, quasi!</p>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-success-outline" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">learn more</button>
       </div>
</div>
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/PyEJ1a6Rk4